# Linux device driver basics

Tags: linux-device-driver

what is the difference between a *device* and a *driver* and how they are related ?
plz explain me in context of below diagram

[image]

Comment: A driver controls a device.
Driver software that is within your Kernel. And a device is hardware.

But if you mean the /dev devices in Linux. Those are just a way for the driver in kernel-space to talk to the user-space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A device is a general device like hardisk, network card etc.
Device driver is a piece of code written to interact with the device, in a more clear way to control the device. It tells how we are going to interact with a device.

The picture you mentioned is related to virtualization:

**Qemu** - is an Emulator means it make virtual CPU, NIC etc. so that Virtual machines can have their own CPU, NIC etc. Think of it like you don't have anything but you are creating an illusion that you have it,

As explained qemu will create emulated devices, now to operate on them we need some drivers. That is where virtio drivers comes into picture.

**Virtio-driver:** These driver are written to control the emulated devices.